# Traduire « Raumliste »

Tags: traduction, allemand

Pour traduire le mot allemand *Raum*/*Raumliste* en Français.
Je veux une traduction exacte.
*Raum*, ce n'est pas *Zimmer* (chambre).

Est-ce que *liste des pièces* est correct, ou doit on dire *liste des locaux* ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Il faudrait plus d'éléments de contexte pour répondre précisément.

La *liste des pièces* convient sans doute très bien pour lister les pièces d'un immeuble.

La *liste des locaux* donne un sous-entendu commercial, et on comprend aussi que les locaux ne sont pas dans le même immeuble (ex: *liste des locaux commerciaux de Normandie*, *liste des locaux vacants à Paris*)

Si c'est pour lister les chambres d'un hôtel, alors ce sera *liste des chambres*.